# Array declaration fails while trying to declare int array

Tags: c

I've been learning & coding sorting algorithms for some time and recently I've coded **merge sort** in C, and I've also coded a **sort_test** function to test the function that I write. In the sort test function, I'm declaring an array and assigning random values to it, but when the array size gets to 1,000,000 the program crashes. Why is that happening?

#### `sort_test.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include "merge_sort.h"
#include "sort_test.h"

// test size
#define MIN 10
#define MAX 1000000

// int comparator

int cmpInt(const void *elem1,const void * elem2){
    int e1 = *(int *)elem1; // i-1
    int e2 = *(int *)elem2; // i
    if(e2 < e1){
        return -1;
    } else if(e2 > e1){
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

// double comparator

int cmpDouble(const void *elem1,const void *elem2){
    double e1 = *(double *)elem1;
    double e2 = *(double *)elem2;
    if(e2 < e1){
        return -1;
    } else if(e2 > e1){
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

void initSeed(){
    srand(time(NULL));
}

void intSortTest(){
    initSeed();
    for(size_t i = MIN;i <= MAX;i *=10){
        int arr[i];
        for(size_t j = 0; j < i;j++){
            arr[j] = rand();
        }
        // sorting the array
        mergesort(arr,0,i);
        // checking if sorted array hold the 
        // condition i[0] <= i[1] ... <= i[n].
        for(size_t j = 1;j < i;j++){
            int *e1 = &arr[j-1];
            int *e2 = &arr[j];
        assert(cmpInt(e2,e1) <= 0);
        }
        printf("INT TEST : %7d\tPASSED\n",i);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void doubleSortTest(){
    initSeed();
    for(int i = MIN; i <= MAX; i *= 10){
        double arr[i];
        for(int j = 0 ; j < i;j++){
            arr[j] = (double)(rand() % 100) + 1.0;
        }
        // perform sort
        //insertion_sort(arr,sizeof (double),i,cmpDouble);
        for(int j = 1; j < i;j++){
            double *e1 = &arr[j-1];
            double *e2 = &arr[j];
            assert(cmpDouble(e2,e1) <= 0);
        }
        printf("Double Test : %5d\tPASSED\n",i);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

#### `sort_test.h`

```
#ifndef SORT_TEST_H
#define SORT_TEST_H

void initSeed();
void intSortTest();
void doubleSortTest();
int cmpDouble(const void *elem1,const void *elem2);
int cmpInt(const void *elem1,const void * elem2);

#endif // SORT_TEST_H
```

#### `merge_sort.h`

```
#ifndef MERGE_SORT_H
#define MERGE_SORT_H

void mergesort(int *arr,int start,int end);
void merge(int *arr,int start,int med,int end);

#endif // MERGE_SORT_H
```

#### `merge_sort.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "sort_test.h"
#include "merge_sort.h"

int main(){
    intSortTest();
    return 0;
}

void mergesort(int *arr,int start,int end){
    if(start < end){
        int median = (end + start) / 2;
        mergesort(arr,start,median);
        mergesort(arr,median+1,end);
        merge(arr,start,median,end);
    }
}

void merge(int *arr,int start,int median,int end){
    int i = start; int j = median+1;
    int copy[end+1];
    int cIndex = 0;

    while(i <= median && j <= end) {
        if(arr[j] <= arr[i]){
            copy[cIndex++] = arr[j++];
        } else {
            copy[cIndex++] = arr[i++];
        }
    }

    while(i <= median){
        copy[cIndex++] = arr[i++];
    }
    while(j <= end){
        copy[cIndex++] = arr[j++];
    }
    for(int k = 0; k < cIndex; k++){
        arr[start++] = copy[k];
    }
}
```

Comment: Most probably you’ve got a stack overflow, trying to allocate too much array on the stack.  If you’re on Windows, the default stack size is 1 MiB; on Unix-like systems, it is normally 8 MiB. It sounds like you’re on a Unix-like system and have allocated one million 4-byte integers twice and thereby blew your stack.

Comment: Adding to @JonathanLeffler's comment, try dynamically allocating the arrays instead.

Comment: Now the question is self-contained.  It isn't minimal because you still have the 'double code' in there which is not germane to your question, but it should be compilable under sufficiently lax compiler options (note that declarations such as  `void initSeed();` in `sort_test.h` are not prototypes — you'd need `void initSeed(void);` to make it into a prototype).  Also, embedding `main()` in `merge_sort.c` is a fairly bad mistake; it should be in `sort_test.c` if it isn't in its own file.  You couldn't use the `merge_sort.c` with `main()` in any other program.

Comment: Note that an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) (or MRE or whatever name SO now uses), or an SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)) would not include the code related to `double` type — your immediate problem is with the `int` code, not the `double` code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you are allocating the arrays on the stack. Try the following code instead.

```
void intSortTest(){
    initSeed();
    for(size_t i = MIN;i <= MAX;i *=10){
        int *arr = malloc(i*sizeof(int));  // <-- changed this
        for(size_t j = 0; j < i;j++){
            arr[j] = rand();
        }
        // sorting the array
        mergesort(arr,0,i);
        // checking if sorted array hold the 
        // condition i[0] <= i[1] ... <= i[n].
        for(size_t j = 1;j < i;j++){
            int *e1 = &arr[j-1];
            int *e2 = &arr[j];
            assert(cmpInt(e2,e1) <= 0);
        }
        printf("INT TEST : %7d\tPASSED\n",i);
        free(arr);   // <-- added this
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

**EDIT**

Also the merge algorithm is incorrect. More precisely, you have a problem with the value list boundaries.

When you define the start and end index of a value list, the values are in `arr[start]` to `arr[end-1]`, not `arr[end]`. The number of values is then `end-start`. With this convention, you have an empty list when `start == end`.

As a consequence, the function `mergesort` becomes:

```
void mergesort(int *arr,int start,int end){
    if (start+1 >= end) 
        return; // a list with 0 or 1 values is already sorted
    int median = (end + start) / 2;
    mergesort(arr,start,median);
    mergesort(arr,median,end);
    merge(arr,start,median,end);
}
```

The merge function then become as follow:

```
void merge(int *arr,int start,int median,int end){
    int i = start; int j = median;
    int *copy = malloc((end-start)*sizeof(int)); // use malloc for huge arrays
    int cIndex = 0;

    while(i < median && j < end) {  // not i <= median && j <= end
        if(arr[j] <= arr[i]){
            copy[cIndex++] = arr[j++];
        } else {
            copy[cIndex++] = arr[i++];
        }
    }

    while(i < median){ // not i <= median
        copy[cIndex++] = arr[i++];
    }
    while(j < end){  // not j <= median
        copy[cIndex++] = arr[j++];
    }
    for(int k = 0; k < cIndex; k++){
        arr[start++] = copy[k];
    }
    free(copy);
}
```

As you can see, there are only minor differences.

With this code, your program runs without error.

Comment: @Kessinger there are other places where you allocate the array on the stack: `doubleSortTest`. The program may now crash because you overflow the array (write in it beyond its end). With heap allocated blocks this can cause a segmentation fault. You thus have to check your code.

Comment: @Kessinger your merge algorithm is incorrect. The problem is with the boundaries of the list of values to merge. I updated my answer to provide you the corrected merge functions.

Answer (score 0):

Now that the code is visible, it is fairly easy to see that you are indeed blowing the stack as I suggested in one of my many [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60124355/array-declaration-fails-while-trying-to-declare-int-array?noredirect=1#comment106339894_60124355).

In `merge()`, you have:

```
int copy[end+1];
```

as well as in `intSortTest()` having:

```
int arr[i];
```

where `i` reaches 1,000,000.

When `end` is 1,000,000 — it is set from `i` — you have an array of one million `int` values being sorted, and a copy with another one million `int` values (plus 1), so you attempt to place two million 4-byte `int` values on the stack — and 8,000,000 bytes blows the stack limits.  Since 800,000 bytes (the previous size) fits on the stack in both Unix and Windows, it isn't 100% clear which you are using.  There isn't much margin for error on Unix/Linux; the limit is thoroughly blown on Windows because neither 4 MB array fits on the stack.

The recommended fix is to use dynamic memory allocation (`malloc()` et al) instead of stack allocation — in both the sort test function and in the main `merge()` code.